# Remove the circular points in a line chart

Tags: r, visualization, echarts4r

Using echarts4r package for R, is there a way to remove the selectable circular points in a line series?  For example

```
mtcars %>% e_charts(mpg) %>% e_title("MTCARS", "Test chart") %>% 
    e_line(drat) %>% e_line(wt)
```

Zooming in on the chart, there are the little circular points.

[image: Circular points in line chart]

This is OK when there are not too many, however when the data set is large, these circles create a bubble bath effect and hide the lines.

Comment: Nothing wrong with a nice hot bubble bath, especially if they hide (unwanted) lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the symbol argument to the e_line function:

```
library(echarts4r)
mtcars %>% e_charts(mpg) %>% e_title("MTCARS", "Test chart") %>% 
  e_line(drat, symbol='none') %>% e_line(wt, symbol='none')
```

see: https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line for more info. :)